# How to show make command's output in vertically split buffer?

Tags: makeprg

I want the behavior of `:vnew term://make ts run-server` but using the `make` command instead of invoking `term`. I have tried `:make ts run-server | vert copen` but that still takes over the entire terminal until it's finished, and then it opens a vertically split buffer, but I want it to open a vertically split buffer and have all the output in that new buffer only.

As for why I want this, 2 reasons: 1) I'm curious how to do it, and 2) using `term` doesn't give me the quickfix list.

EDIT: I want to do this without plugins. If this functionality isn't possible without a plugin, I will content myself with `:vnew term://make ts run-server`.

Comment: Related: [How to capture errors from make in terminal window](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/16432/how-to-capture-errors-from-make-in-terminal-window)

Comment: @Matt You're right, that is very related. Looks like it isn't really possible :(

Comment: That's possible with the help of jobs API. But, in practice, that will result in some sort of lightweight re-implementation of the corresponding plugins (AsyncRun, vim-dispatch etc.).

Answer (score 3):

Your first command was closer: `:vnew` makes a new vertical window. `:vertical` is the modifier that changes how other commands work:

```
:vertical terminal make ts run-server
```

Will get you the terminal. If you want that *and* the quickfix list, try tpope's Dispatch plugin:

```
:Dispatch make ts run-server
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Actually `:vertical terminal make ts run-server` is different from `:vnew term://make ts run-server`, and as such does not do what I want. I'd prefer not to use a plugin for this because I'm fairly certain this should be possible without a plugin. If it requires a plugin then I just won't do this at all.

Comment: @JasonFry the `:vert terminal make` is the way to go without a plugin, however your use of `term://` makes it sound like you are using neovim, so the command might be a bit different there.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt You're correct, I'm using neovim and `:vertical terminal make ts run-server` behaves differently from `:vnew term://make ts run-server`.

Are you saying this isn't possible without invoking `term`? That's a bummer.

Comment: @JasonFry `vert term` simply doesn't work in Neovim. But that's not a problem, as you can always do `vnew | term ...` etc.

Comment: @JasonFry There are other ways, like capturing the output of `system` and put it in a new buffer or similar. But the built-in terminal is the most straight forward way.